# Return nodes which do not have a property value in another node set

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm rather new to Neo4j, but have not been able to find what I'm looking for in the documentation. I'm using version 3.5 which does not support sub queries.

I have two sets of nodes, which for simplicity's sake I'll call `Rocks` and `Bicycles`. These sets have some similar properties, but no relationships and they are entirely distinct - there are no nodes in `Rocks` which are in `Bicycles`. However, they may have the same value for a particular property called "color". But for a node in `Rocks` that property is spelled `color` and for a node in `Bicycles` it's spelled `colour`.

What I want is to return all the nodes in `Bicycles` which do not have a `colour` value found in any of the nodes in `Rocks`.

Here's my query to return all the colors of the nodes in `Rocks`:

```
MATCH (r:Rocks) WITH r.color AS excludecolors RETURN excludecolors
```

Which returns exactly what I expect - a list of hex values for the colors: `["ff5733", "#0a8a00", "4f28ff", ...]`

Now I want to return all the colors in `Bicycles` *EXCLUSIVE* of the colors that I found in the set of `Rocks`

```
MATCH (r:Rocks) WITH r.color AS excludecolors RETURN excludecolors
MATCH (b:Bicycles) WHERE NOT b.colour IN [excludecolors] RETURN DISTINCT b.colour
```

However, this returns everything in Bicycles - including the colors in `excludecolors`! I can exclude them manually by entering particular values I want to exclude:

```
MATCH (b:Bicycles) WHERE NOT b.colour IN ["ff5733", "#0a8a00"] RETURN DISTINCT b.colour
```

but there are far too many to do by hand. How can I return only the colors found in `Bicycles` and not in `Rocks`? The closest equivalent I can think of would be the SQL outer join, but I'm quite stumped about how to do this in cypher

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
MATCH (r:Rocks)
WITH COLLECT(DISTINCT r.color) AS excludeColors
MATCH (b:Bicycles)
WHERE NOT b.colour IN excludeColors
RETURN DISTINCT b.colour
```

Comment: This works perfectly! Does collect force the output to be a list whereas in my previous one it didn't?

Comment: Yes. See documentation on [aggregating functions](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/aggregating/) for full details.